# Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 11

Tags: javascript, json

I have an array in string and I want to convert it to array again , But when I use `JSON.parse(data)` , javascrept gives me this error :

`Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 11`

So how can I convert this string to array or fix this error ?

```
var data = `[
    ['1','2','3'],
    ['3','4','5','6']
]`;

var d = JSON.parse(data);
```

I get this data from an api and I can't change `'` to `"`

Answer (score 1):

In JSON, strings are delimited with `"` (U+0022 : QUOTATION MARK) characters, only `"` characters, and never `'` (U+0027 : APOSTROPHE) characters.

Comment: But I get data from an api and I cant change `'` to `"`

Comment: cant you spilt your string and change it to ```"```  before parsing @evan